String data from fgets is lost when using printf
I am new to C programming, and right now doing my first assignment in a C course.
I have noticed an unusual behavior when using a string in my code.
I am currently writing a simple string encoder, our task was to use a pointer to a char array of length 5, initialized to the empty string. We are also supposed to get a string from the user using fgets.
I'm sure I have many problems with my C code, but for now I would really like to know what's causing this behavior (two lines of printing the input string, divided by a usual printf, in the second line of printing the string is lost).
You can see the terminal output in the screenshot below the code (current string 2: *)
char *get_string() {
    char str[100];
    puts("Please enter a string");
    return fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct fun_desc {
        char *name;
        char (*fun)(char);
    };

    char (*nullFunction)(char) = NULL;
    struct fun_desc menu[] = {
        { "Get String", my_get },
        { "Print Decimal", dprt },
        { "Print Hex", xprt },
        { "Print Character", cprt },
        { "Encrypt", encrypt },
        { "Decrypt", decrypt },
        { NULL, nullFunction }
    };

    int flag = 1;
    int i, opNum;
    char functions[5] = "";
    char *carray = functions;

    while (flag) {
        printf("Current string 1: %s", carray);
        printf("Select operation from the following menu:\n");
        printf("Current string 2: %s", carray);

        puts("\n");
        
        i = 0;
        while (menu[i].fun != NULL) {
            printf("%d) %s\n", i, menu[i].name);
            i++;
        }

        printf("Choose a function by entering it's number\n");

        char op[4];

        if (fgets(op, sizeof(op), stdin) == NULL)
            flag = 0;
        else {
            opNum = atoi(op);
            if (opNum >= 0 && opNum < 6) {
                puts("Within bounds");
                if (opNum == 0)
                    carray = get_string();
                else
                    carray = map(carray, 5, menu[opNum].fun);
            } else {
                puts("Not within bounds");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    puts("\nEnd of input\n");

    return 0;
}



Using the returned pointer of the function get_string invokes undefined behavior because the function returns a pointer to an array with automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function.

... so getstring() should either be passed a buffer to use, or allocate one for the caller to free() later. Or, it could use static char str[100];.

your char str[100]; only exists for the scope of the "get_string" function. You could either pass in a char* as a parameter or declare "char str[100];" outside your function to make it static

The function get_string returns a pointer to an array with automatic storage that must not be accessed after it goes out of scope when the function returns.
The program has undefined behavior.
You should allocate the string from the heap:
char *s = fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
return s ? strdup(s) : s;

